# Undefined scss variable false negative using Gulp and Blendid

Tags: sass, gulp, bootstrap-4

For some reason I get these false negatives when using variables in scss, see error message bellow or screenshot (https://dha4w82d62smt.cloudfront.net/items/0D2t3G3a3U47060t3v44/Image%202018-02-28%20at%203.13.02%20PM.png?X-CloudApp-Visitor-Id=2833541&v=63ac4800)

```
[15:11:06] gulp-notify: [Error running Gulp] Error in plugin 'gulp-sass'
Message:
    ../../src/stylesheets/custom/style.scss
Error:
Undefined variable:
"$font-size-sm".
        on line 2 of ../../src/stylesheets/custom/style.scss
>>   font-size:
$font-size-sm;
   -------------^
Details:
    status:
1
    file:
/Users/andreas/Coding/mittanbud/emg-styleguide/src/stylesheets/custom/style.scss
    line:
2
    column:
14
    formatted:
```

My directory structure is like this:

```
/stylesheets/bootstrap
/stylesheets/custom/custom_variables.scss
/stylesheets/custom/style.scss
/stylesheets/app.scss
```

and my app.scss looks like this:

```
@import "custom/custom_variables";
@import "bootstrap/bootstrap"; 
@import "custom/style";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to import the Bootstrap vars first...

```
@import "bootstrap/variables"; 
@import "custom/custom_variables";
@import "bootstrap/bootstrap"; 
@import "custom/style";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that didn't work either. It caused the following errors: https://dha4w82d62smt.cloudfront.net/items/1r2n2p0r3w1Q1S3Z3o1v/Image%202018-03-01%20at%2011.25.29%20AM.png?X-CloudApp-Visitor-Id=2833541&v=bfe0a5d5 and the css didn't compile successfully.

Comment: That's a [different issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23804) than the original question. Make sure you're using the latest 4.0.0

Comment: I know it's a different issue, but it still doesn't solve the original issue. I am using the latest version 4.0.0. Thanks for your effort to help me though. Hope someone else is able to help me.

Comment: Did you follow the link? Are you using the latest 4.0.0 or 4.0 beta?